# What is the name of the study of animal mind and behavior?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Is there a term for the knowledge domain that deals with *animal mind and behavior*?

Initially, I'd thought that it is "[Zoology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoology)", but it doesn't look like a fit.

Basically I was wondering if the study of human mind and behavior is called "[Psychology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology)", what is the name for the study of animal mind and behavior?

Comment: Man is an animal.

Comment: @Kris Since "man" is a subset of animal, we can't use Psychology to refer to the "study of animal mind and behavior" right?

Comment: No, Pacerier. Psychology applies to animals too. Think about it - Pavlova studied dogs, Skinner studied rats and pigeons, psychologists are forever putting animals in mazes, and getting them to solve puzzles. Psychology can apply to animals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Ethology*, *Animal Behavior*, and *Comparative Psychology* all are recognized disciplines dealing with various aspects of animal behavior and psychology.

The fine distinctions and boundaries between these areas are often subject to debate -- in fact they seem to overlap to a great extent.

See [**Ethology** on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethology) for interesting insights. (Not to be confused with 'ethnology'.)

Comment: I have deliberately restricted my answer to the scope of EL&U, i.e., the English terminology aspect alone, avoiding technical details.

Comment: Note that *ethology* can also apply to lower-taxa animals such as insects (like crickets) and spiders, as well as mammals. I am not sure you would talk about the psychology of spiders. But as Kris says, some of that discussion is beyond the scope of ELU. *Ethology* is the correct word.